# make ScrollViewer resize when the MainWindow resizes

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

This is an attempt to implement a read-only Linux text file (one byte newline sequence) viewer for Windows.

It presently has a ScrollViewer that will not resize when the WPF MainWindow is resized. How do I make the ScrollViewer size subservient to the MainWindow?

```
    private void ScrollViewer1GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = 
                new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Document";
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; 
        dlg.Filter = null;

        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            string filename = dlg.FileName;

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filename,
                                          System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
            flowDocument.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
            flowDocument.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Lucida Console");
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(text);
            flowDocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

            FlowDocumentScrollViewer fdsv = new FlowDocumentScrollViewer();
            fdsv.Document = flowDocument;
            ScrollViewer1.Content = fdsv;
        }
    }

    private void MainWindow1SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow1" x:Class="ReadOnlyViewLinux1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ReadOnlyView" Height="256" Width="512" SizeChanged="MainWindow1SizeChanged">
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="236" Margin="10,10,0,-21" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="492" GotFocus="ScrollViewer1GotFocus"/>
```

Comment: -1. I don't see any ScrollViewer *declared* in your code.

Comment: I'll add the XAML to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply Leave the ScrollViewer with no `Height`, `Width`, or `Margin` properties:

```
<Window>
  <ScrollViewer/>
</Window>
```